# Batch File to Delete a folder if it doesnt contain a specific file

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch-file

I have a folder with loads of subfolders. I need a batch file that looks down the list of subfolders and checks if a specified file exists. If the file does not exist then the sub folder can be deleted.

This needs to run on Windows 7 workstations.

I am getting my syntax mixed up in my for /f and if exist commands:

```
for /f /f%% in ('dir /b c:\test') do if exist "test.txt" rename c:\test\%% tobedeleted
```

I think I am either trying to do to much in one argument or am missing something vital.

Answer (score 2):

#### If the file does not exist then the sub folder can be deleted.

You need something like the following:

```
echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%i in ('dir /a:d /b /s c:\test') do (
  set _dir=%%i
  if exist !_dir!\test.txt (
    rem do nothing
    ) else (
    echo rd !_dir!
    )
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Remove the `echo` before `rd` when you are sure the correct directories will be deleted.
- Add `/s` to `rd` if the directory contains subdirectories.
- Add `/q` to `rd` to remove Y/N confirmation.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [if](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) - Conditionally perform a command.
- [enabledelayedexpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) - Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution time rather than at parse time.
- [rd](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) - Delete folder(s).
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.